# Rails redirect back to root with Bootstrap-tour

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just pushed my RoR application to my staging server and am seeing some odd behavior when I go to a page... it loads then redirects me back to my root_path!  This is not the behavior I am seeing in my localhost development environment, which is making it hard for me to debug.  I'm hoping someone has seen this type of issue before and/or has some suggestions on how to fix...

I'm navigating to `NetworkHosts#show`:

```
class NetworkHostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_network_host, only: [:show]
  before_action :get_company_and_locations

    def show
      @network_host = NetworkHost.find(params[:id])
      if @network_host   
        @major_issues = get_host_issues(@network_host, @network_host.last_test, "major")
        @minor_issues = get_host_issues(@network_host, @network_host.last_test, "minor")
      end
    end

    private

      def set_network_host
        @network_host = NetworkHost.find(params[:id])
      end
end
```

The `before_action :set_company_and_locations` method is in `application_helper.rb`

```
def get_company_and_locations
  @company = current_user.company
  @devices =  Device.where(company_id: @company.id).order(name: :asc)
  @locations = if @company
    current_user.company_locations.order(:name)
  else
    []
  end
end
```

`NetworkHostsController#show` loads, but then redirects me right back to my root path.  I don't have a redirect reference in the controller method, so the behavior I'm seeing doesn't make sense.

Here is what I'm seeing in my log file:

```
[2016-09-08T08:52:05.731929 #24533]  INFO -- : Started GET "/network_hosts/61" for 102.12.33.232 at 2016-09-08 08:52:05 -0500
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.736988 #24533]  INFO -- : Processing by NetworkHostsController#show as HTML
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.737089 #24533]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"61"}
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.758847 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_back_button.html.erb (0.4ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.775550 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_network_host_modal.html.erb (1.4ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.779707 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered network_hosts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (21.4ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.780110 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.795524 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (14.9ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.796621 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_topnav.html.erb (0.9ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.796919 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.797293 #24533]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_tour.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:05.797636 #24533]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 24.8ms | ActiveRecord: 22.7ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:06.591084 #24536]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 102.12.33.232 at 2016-09-08 08:52:06 -0500
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:06.593433 #24536]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:07.341991 #24536]  INFO -- :   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (358.4ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:07.342596 #24536]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:07.357271 #24536]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (13.8ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:07.358451 #24536]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_topnav.html.erb (1.0ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:07.358761 #24536]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:07.359163 #24536]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_tour.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2016-09-08T08:52:07.359594 #24536]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 766ms (Views: 303.2ms | ActiveRecord: 178.1ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Again, this doesn't happen on my localhost, so I'm lost on how to troubleshoot.  Thanks!

**Update**

With some help, it looks like my [`Bootstrap-tour`](http://bootstraptour.com/api/) javascript which is loaded in the `_tour` partial is causing the redirect.

> _tour.html.erb

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tour').click(function() {
    tour.restart();
  });

  var tour = new Tour({
      steps: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-1",
          title: "<h3>Navigation</h3>",
          content: "This menu is what you will use to navigate through the results that Neo gives you.",
          placement: "right"
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-2",
          title: "<h3>Home Dashboard</h3>",
          content: "The Home dashboard is an executive overview of your security results, as well as tons of other useful (high-level) information.",
          placement: "right"
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-3",
          title: "<h3>Locations</h3>",
          content: "Select a specific location to see what devices and security issues Neo has found on your network.",
          placement: "right"
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-4",
          title: "<h3>Network</h3>",
          content: "The network view will give you an overall view of all of your network devices across all locations.",
          placement: "right"
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-5",
          title: "<h3>Information</h3>",
          content: "You'll find Reports, Audit Logs, and Scan History here.",
          placement: "right"
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-6",
          title: "<h3>Settings</h3>",
          content: "You can control when and how your Neo operates on your network by selecting a specific Neo and adjusting its settings.",
          placement: "right"
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-7",
          title: "<h3>The Dashboard</h3>",
          content: "This is your dashboard where you'll find quick information to give you an overview of your security layout.  <br/><br/> Don't worry if you don't see much yet. Your Neo takes a litte time to collect the information to display.",
          placement: "bottom"
        },
        {
          path: "/",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-8",
          title: "<h3>Profile</h3>",
          content: "With this dropdown menu, you'll manage your user profile, add a Neo to your account, log out, and be able to get help.",
          placement: "left"
        },
        {
          path: "/locations/new",
          element: ".tour-step.tour-step-9",
          title: "<h3>Add Your Neo</h3>",
          content: "Now, to finish up, lets add a Neo to your profile...<br/><br/>You'll need the serial number provided to you and a good name!",
          placement: "left",
        }
      ],
      backdrop: true,
      backdropPadding: 10,
    });
    tour.init();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Might it be worth commenting out the code int he action, on the staging server, restarting the server and seeing if it still happens.

Comment: You mean comment out the `show` method?

Comment: That's not a real _redirect_, you are seeing `Completed 200 OK` - the page has been rendered successfully and then you are visiting the next resource. The first thing that comes to mind is that javascript is being executed which changes `windows.location`, is there something happening on the frontend side?

Comment: @Magnuss good call, I was just looking at that... looks like my `bootstrap-tour` which is loaded in the `_tour` partial is causing the redirect... now I have to figure out how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are logged in as an authenticated user in the staging environment?

If you try to load a restricted page with an unauthorised user, you will be redirected to root_path

Comment: Yes, I'm authenticated.

Comment: and you sure you have the permission to the page?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to get to the previous page or any other page for that matter.